# How can I write my query to get information fron a table that link to other table then link to other table and link to other table

Tags: sql, select

```
select 
    d.DVD_catalogno, 
    d.DVD_name, 
    r.mb_id as Member_ID, 
    m.mb_fname, 
    m.mb_lname, 
    r.outstandingfee as Outstandingfine, 
    r.rent_date, 
    due_date, 
    r.daysoverdue
from rent r
inner join Member m on r.mb_id = m.mb_id 
inner join DVD d on d.DVD_catalogno = CatalogNo_No.DVD_catalogno 
    and CatalogNo_No.DVD_no = rent_CatalogNo_No.DVD_no 
    and rent_CatalogNo_No.rent_id = rent.rent_id
where r.outstandingfee > 0
```

I want to get the data that need to pass through a lot of table but it show my code have error start from

```
inner join DVD d on d.DVD_catalogno = CatalogNo_No.DVD_catalogno 
and CatalogNo_No.DVD_no = rent_CatalogNo_No.DVD_no 
and rent_CatalogNo_No.rent_id = rent.rent_id
```

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 31 The multi-part identifier "CatalogNo_No.DVD_catalogno" could not be bound. Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 32 The multi-part identifier "CatalogNo_No.DVD_no" could not be bound. Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 32 The multi-part identifier "rent_CatalogNo_No.DVD_no" could not be bound. Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 33 The multi-part identifier "rent_CatalogNo_No.rent_id" could not be bound. Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 33 The multi-part identifier "rent.rent_id" could not be bound.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 31
The multi-part identifier "CatalogNo_No.DVD_catalogno" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 32
The multi-part identifier "CatalogNo_No.DVD_no" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 32
The multi-part identifier "rent_CatalogNo_No.DVD_no" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 33
The multi-part identifier "rent_CatalogNo_No.rent_id" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 33
The multi-part identifier "rent.rent_id" could not be bound.

Comment: `CatalogNo_No` is the 4-th table that you mentioned in the question title, right?

Comment: In this query CatalogNo_No doesn’t exist

Comment: maybe yes...... I think

Comment: there is a table name CatalogNo_No

Comment: You bind dvd as d and rent as r.  There is no CatalogNo_No table as far as that query as concerned

Comment: What about `rent_CatalogNo_No`, is it also a table?

Comment: but how can I bind Catalog_No where to bind?

Comment: yes rent_CatalogNo_No is also a table

Comment: Doesn’t matter he selects from rent, and joins member and dvd.  Those are the only tables that query is looking at.

Comment: select d.DVD_catalogno, d.DVD_name, r.mb_id as Member_ID,  m.mb_fname, m.mb_lname, r.outstandingfee 
  as Outstandingfine , r.rent_date, due_date, r.daysoverdue
    from rent r inner join Member m on r.mb_id = m.mb_id 
  inner join DVD d, catalogno_no on d.DVD_catalogno =     CatalogNo_No.DVD_catalogno 
  and CatalogNo_No.DVD_no =     rent_CatalogNo_No.DVD_no 
  and rent_CatalogNo_No.rent_id = rent.rent_id
    where r.outstandingfee > 0

Comment: if I write like this the "on" will have error

Comment: You’re trying to use a table you never called as a reference for your joins....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to join to each of the four tables, even the tables from which you do not pull any fields. Currently, your query has only three tables, but the query condition references five.

Here is how you fix it - add `Rent_CatalogNo_No` and `CatalogNo_No` to the list of joined tables, and distribute conditions from the last `ON` to the corresponding `ON` clauses of the added tables:

```
SELECT
    d.DVD_catalogno
,   d.DVD_name
,   r.mb_id as Member_ID
,   m.mb_fname
,   m.mb_lname
,   r.outstandingfee as Outstandingfine
,   r.rent_date
,   r.due_date
,   r.daysoverdue
FROM Rent r
INNER JOIN Member m ON r.mb_id = m.mb_id
INNER JOIN Rent_CatalogNo_No rc ON r.rent_id = rc.rent_id
INNER JOIN CatalogNo_No c ON rc.DVD_no = c.DVD_no
INNER JOIN DVD d on c.DVD_catalogno = d.DVD_catalogno
where r.outstandingfee > 0
```